# Is there a tiling WM that allows to place a common background window for all workspaces persisting the ability to use tiling algorithms?

Tags: workspaces, dwm, tiling-wm, productivity

Recently, I came across the idea of placing a window with currently
playing video behind transparent terminal, [like this](https://devrant.com/rants/578226/holy-fuck-i-didnt-expect-this-simple-terminal-from-suckless-org-aka-st-after-app).  At the
moment, I am using `dwm`, and I can implement a simple case of this idea
with one video and one transparent terminal using monocle layout
(placing a window with video behind a terminal), but I want to implement
more complicated things:

1. to make one background window with video that will be common for all
   tags/workspaces - so it will be possible to switch tags/workspaces while
   persisting background video;
2. to have an opportunity to use tiling layout algorithm above the
   window with video.

There is a [sticky patch](https://dwm.suckless.org/patches/sticky/) for dwm that allows to have a common window
for all tags, but I didn't find the way how to persist background
monocle client on other tags with tiling layout (frankly, I doubt that
this is possible in dwm).

I think that this would be possible if there were some kind of
containers that can store different layouts on different layers
(sub-layouts?), so, for example, I could create container with "deck"
layout, place video in bottom element and activate "tiling" layout in
upper element, but even in that case I don't know how to persist video
between different workspaces...

Is there any way to do such things in dwm or any other tiling wm?

Comment: It is easy in dwm to get a window to be visible across all tags. I think the default keybinding is mod-shift-0 or something similar. Something that sounds similar but not the same as what you ask for would be to have a floating window (your video) attached to every tag, with the tiling layout set. The only objection to that I see is that the video is on top, and I presume you want it at the back. Whichever window is at the front will of course need to have some transparency.

Comment: I do not know if you can "push floating windows to the back" in dwm, but that would fully fit your use case I think. If it is not possible, then patching in that functionality is one avenue to getting what you want.

Another option is to experiment with modifying the "centered floating master" layout, patched in here: https://dwm.suckless.org/patches/centeredmaster/. This layout has a master window in the center with slave windows in columns behind. But, interestingly, focusing on the slaves will push the master behind. This is your other option.